# Booting with higher resolution console and NVIDIA drivers

Tags: fedora, boot, fonts, console

I switched from Nouveau to proprietary NVIdia drivers in my Fedora 34 because the former were hard freezing my computer. Now when I boot (always in text mode), the fonts are too big. I tried the usual fixes and did not work.

Following [this wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB/Tips_and_tricks#Setting_the_framebuffer_resolution), I added

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x16,auto
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

to `/etc/default/grub`, run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, and reboot. Same ugly resolution.

The `1024x768x16` I got from the output of `hwinfo --framebuffer`.

I also tried with  `GRUB_GFXMODE=1680x1050x16,auto`, same problem.

Any clues?

Comment: You're booting with 1024x768 resolution, so yeah, the font will look big. Any system produced in the past 15 years can do better. I'd check the monitor / laptop specs to see what's the actual native resolution and set it in grub accordingly.

Comment: No. I am booting with with an even lower resolution. I want 1024x768.